# npm run build is always manually run after pushing in Azure app service

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service

I have a react node application in Azure app service. Inside one of my react code is a environment variable `REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY` that is saved in my Azure application configuration settings.

The environment variable is properly read from the configuration settings only if `npm run build` is manually run in the Azure Debug Console.

Is there a way for the app to automatically read the environment variables from the application configuration settings without manually running the `npm run build` command after pushing in the repository?

Comment: Check out App Configuration client library for JavaScript: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/app-configuration-readme?view=azure-node-latest

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [App Configuration client library for JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/app-configuration-readme?view=azure-node-latest).

**To install:**

```
npm install @azure/app-configuration
```

**Usage:**

```
const setting = await client.getConfigurationSetting({
  key: "hello"
});

setting.value = "new value!";
await client.setConfigurationSetting(setting);

// fields unrelated to just identifying the setting are simply
// ignored (for instance, the `value` field)
await client.setReadOnly(setting, true);

// delete just needs to identify the setting so other fields are
// just ignored
await client.deleteConfigurationSetting(setting);
```

Comment: Can I do this on a react file? I want to do this on a JSX file instead of doing it in Express